# How to get Fitting SVG Art-board to Selected Artwork using PathIterator class in Java

Tags: java, svg, fonts

I am trying to get the boundaries of a text into worksheet content selection .
I am writing coed in java using `AttributedString` class to get the coordinates of the text by using `PathIterator` class, the i save it into SVG format , when i open the svg file, it displays the Text but in somewhere in the worksheet . It is right that, but my question How to resize page to content(or resize page to drawing selection, which is the text), i am using `Inkscape` for displaying the text, where there is an option it allow you to resize the page(worksheet) to the content as this example there 
[resize page to content](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-N6hh3wgnlOs/U3ga9DvXcCI/AAAAAAAAZUQ/7kDlu_ksHC4/s1600/01-10_by_10_pepperoni.png)

I tried this code which is for saving and getting the coordinates of the text:

```
public class pathsFont {

public pathsFont(){
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    pathsFont getFiel=new pathsFont();
    getFiel.getFontFileAsSVG(new FileWriter("C:\\paths01.svg")); }

Shape shape ;
public void getFontFileAsSVG(FileWriter f) throws IOException{
    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40);
    String str="Hello";
    AttributedString attributedString = new AttributedString(str);
    attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, font, 0, str.length());
    attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.WIDTH, shape);
   FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = new FontRenderContext(null, false, false);
   TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(attributedString.getIterator(), fontRenderContext);
   //to set a specific position 
      AffineTransform at=new AffineTransform();
      at.translate(10,20);

    shape = layout.getOutline(at);
    PathIterator pi = shape.getPathIterator(at);

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(f);

        out.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n<svg\n>" );
        out.println("<path d=\"");

        String temp=new String();

        while (pi.isDone() == false) {
             temp+=getCoordinates(pi);
            pi.next();
          }

              out.println(temp);
            out.format("\"/>"+"\n"+"</svg>");
             out.close();
             f.close();
             System.out.println("Data added to the File successfully");
}

public String getCoordinates(PathIterator pi) {
  String temp=new String();
double[] coor = new double[6];
int type = pi.currentSegment(coor);
switch (type) {
case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
  temp="\n\n"+" M " + coor[0] + ", " + coor[1];
  break;
case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
  temp+="\n\n"+" L " + coor[0] + ", " + coor[1];
  break;
case PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO:
  temp+=" Q " + coor[0] + ", " + coor[1] + " "
      + coor[2] + ", " + coor[3];
  break;
case PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO:
  temp+=" C " + coor[0] + ", " + coor[1] + " "
      + coor[2] + ", " + coor[3] + " " + coor[4] + ", " + coor[5];
  break;
case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
  temp+=" Z";
  break;
default:
  break;
}
return temp; }}
```

if some part of the question not clear please let me know to explain it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution,You should get the Height,Width,X and Y coordinates, that's by using `layout` object of `TextLayout` class,

```
      double w=layout.getBounds().getWidth(); 
      double h=layout.getBounds().getHeight();
      double X=layout.getBounds().getX();
      double Y=layout.getBounds().getY();
```

And then assign these values in svg `viewBox` Attribute .

```
out.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n"
                + "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" preserveAspectRatio=\"none\" " +"\n" 
                + " width=\""+w+"\" height=\""+h+"\""
                + " viewBox=\""+X+" "+Y+" "+w+" "+h+ "\" >" );
```